# Custom error messages in Spring Rest Api validation - ProblemDetails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, validation, hibernate-validator

I am trying to get a ProblemDetail response populated with the message provided on the message attribute of certain controller @Valid annotations.

For example, the `message` attribute on the `@Pattern` annotation:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping
    private ResponseEntity<String> get(@Valid @RequestParam(name = "param")
                                       @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}$",
                                               message = "The request parameter must be 6 characters long and consist of alphanumeric characters.")
                                       String param)  {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

}
```

In case of validation error, I would want a response in the form of a `problem detail`. (cf. [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-ann-rest-exceptions.html) and [RFC-7807](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807)).

Which in this example would look like:

```
{
  "type": "about:blank",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "The request parameter must be 6 characters long and consist of alphanumeric characters.",
  "instance": "/api"
}
```

Note: you can enable this kind of output by having a `@ControllerAdvice` class extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

However, the standard output in this case is:

```
{
  "type": "about:blank",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "Validation failure",
  "instance": "/api"
}
```

`'Validation failure'` is a hard coded message present in the constructor of the `'HandlerMethodValidationException'`, which is the exception being thrown in response to the validation error.

One solution is providing the required message with the message code:

`problemDetail.org.springframework.web.method.annotation.HandlerMethodValidationException`

This works, but limits your messages to be very general. Since another validation error that throws the same exception will have to do with the same message.
It also defeats the purpose of those message attributes on the annotations.

From going through the code my initial guess is that this currently is not yet supported by the spring framework. But maybe someone else has a better idea.

---

Spring boot version: 3.2.2

Spring version: 6.1.3

---

Comment: you didn't enable the message attribute.  server.error.include... Although, from a security point of view, you shouldn't expose too much internals.

Comment: I did try that (server.error.include-message=true). but it had no apparent effect. Neither with server.error.include-binding-errors

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a class annotated with @ControllerAdvice create a method similar to the example below

```java
@ExceptionHandler(value = HandlerMethodValidationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleTenantException(HandlerMethodValidationExceptionex) {

    // here you get your message and return your custom error object (im my example ErrorMessage class)
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is not what I am looking for though, since the ProblemDetail format I would like to use is provided by Spring and has an official spec (RFC7807). Maybe I should refine my question to how to populate the details section of a ProblemDetail object with the message attributes provided on certain Spring annotations.